# css radial gradient causes cpu spikes in flickering in safari and mac os

Tags: javascript, css, safari, webkit

I'm trying to make simple mesh gradient animation in css. It's just 3 divs with radial gradients and scale transforms. In any other browser everything works as intended. But in Safari for some reason there a flickering and cpu spikes.

```
 .mesh_gradient--color {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   position: absolute;
     display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin: auto;
   background: radial-gradient(50% 50% at 50% 50%, #050302 0%, rgba(6, 3, 2, 0) 100%);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 
 @keyframes brownian_motion {
   50% { 
         background-size: 90% 90%;
         background-position: 120% 120%;
         transform: scale(2.5) rotate(-75deg);
   }
 }
 
 @keyframes brownian_motion_2 {
   50% { 
         background-size: 80% 80%;
         background-position: 0 0;
         transform: scale(2.5) rotate(90deg);
   }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jx98y32k/1/

And here is [video](https://youtu.be/deGinabIe58) with flickering in Safari

This is code from website i'm building. I found out about this bug when tested it in Safari and after checking every code i found piece that causes it. I've tried autoprefixing but no luck.

P.S: I thought this problem occurs only in Safari, but it occurs generally on Mac OS

Comment: safari should rip and follow ie :)

Comment: Is  your system using a gpu? I notice on my reasonably powerful laptop that up to 78% of the gpu is being used with Windows10 Edge.

Comment: @AHaworth I think yes, I checked now and when I open this code my GPU goes up to 24%. Any thoughts how to avoid it?

Comment: It sounds more like the other way round, as though macOS isn’t using enough of the gpu. What’s the cpu usage like?

Comment: @AHaworth Spikes up to 50%, my collegues expirienced freezes